# Generate a new Sub Plan/Sequence ID in SQL 2005/8 Business Intelligence Development Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have what is effectively a template SSIS package (well a maintenance plan actually) that is copied and used as the basis of new maintenance plans.

In this package there is a Sequence (or a sub-plan) containing a number of tasks.

I know I can change the package's ID in BIDS, i.e.:

[image]

However I can't change the ID of the sub-plan sequence, the ID is greyed out:

[image]

Neither BIDS for SQL Server 2005 or 2008(R2) allow me to alter this value.

Is there a way to achieve this?

**Rationale:**

To give you some background, these packages are automatically installed on a server using `dtutil`. A script is then run to create a SQL Agent job for the package. Part of that script executes a MSDB system stored procedure called `msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_subplans`. This stored procedure is used to join up the dots between a job, a plan and a sub plan.

For example:

```
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_maintplan_update_subplan
     @subplan_id = @thesubplanid,
     @plan_id = @theplanid,
     @name= @subplanname,
     @description = 'Created by Provisioner',
     @job_id = @jobid,
     @schedule_id = @jobscheduleid_out,
     @allow_create = 1
```

`@plan_id` is the package ID and `@subplan_id` is the sequence or sub-plan ID as shown in the screenshots above.

`sysmaintplan_subplans` adds a record to the table `msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_subplan`, however the primary key is the `subplan_id`. This is why I need to be able to change the ID of the sub-plan in BIDS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [BIDSHelper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/). Fantastic, free tool everyone developing SSIS and probably SSAS should be using.

### Reset GUIDs

"This feature resets the IDs for all tasks, connection managers, configurations, event handlers, variables, and the package ID itself. When you copy a package, objects in both packages end up with the same IDs. This [Reset GUIDs](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Reset%20GUIDs&referringTitle=Documentation) feature ensures that the IDs in the current package are unique."

Comment: Oh this is sweet!